# set sidebar sticky or fixed using tailwind css

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I have a sidebar that works great but when I tried to put it in a sticky/fixed position, the `fixed` class makes the content on the right of the sidebar overrides the sidebar and I try with `sticky` class but doesn't work

this is the sidebar code

```
<div class="md:flex flex-col md:flex-row md:min-h-screen">
    <div @click.away="open = false" class="flex flex-col md:w-64 text-gray-700 bg-white dark-mode:text-gray-200 dark-mode:bg-gray-800 flex-shrink-0 border-t border-gray-200" x-data="{ open: false }">
        <div class="flex-shrink-0 px-8 py-4 flex flex-row items-center justify-between">
            <a href="#" class="text-lg font-semibold tracking-widest text-gray-900 uppercase rounded-lg dark-mode:text-white focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline">Arl</a>
            <button class="rounded-lg md:hidden rounded-lg focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" @click="open = !open">
                <svg fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" class="w-6 h-6">
                    <path x-show="!open" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M3 5a1 1 0 011-1h12a1 1 0 110 2H4a1 1 0 01-1-1zM3 10a1 1 0 011-1h12a1 1 0 110 2H4a1 1 0 01-1-1zM9 15a1 1 0 011-1h6a1 1 0 110 2h-6a1 1 0 01-1-1z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
                    <path x-show="open" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M4.293 4.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 8.586l4.293-4.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414L11.414 10l4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414L10 11.414l-4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414-1.414L8.586 10 4.293 5.707a1 1 0 010-1.414z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
                </svg>
            </button>
        </div>
        <nav :class="{'block': open, 'hidden': !open}" class="flex-grow md:block px-4 pb-4 md:pb-0 md:overflow-y-auto">

            <a class="block px-4 py-2 mt-2 text-xl font-medium text-gray-900 bg-transparent rounded-lg hover:text-gray-900 focus:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-200 focus:bg-gray-200 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" href="{{ url('/calendario') }}"><i class='font-medium mr-5 text-xl bx bx-calendar text-green-600'></i>{{ __('Calendar') }}</a>

            <div @click.away="open = false" class="relative" x-data="{ open: false }">
                <button @click="open = !open" class="flex flex-row items-center w-full px-4 py-2 mt-2 text-sm font-semibold text-left bg-transparent rounded-lg dark-mode:bg-transparent dark-mode:focus:text-white dark-mode:hover:text-white dark-mode:focus:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:hover:bg-gray-600 md:block hover:text-gray-900 focus:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-200 focus:bg-gray-200 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline">
                    <i class='font-medium mr-5 text-xl bx bx-user text-green-600'></i><span class="text-xl font-medium text-gray-900">{{ __('Persons') }}</span>
                    <svg fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" :class="{'rotate-180': open, 'rotate-0': !open}" class="inline w-4 h-4 mt-1 ml-1 transition-transform duration-200 transform md:-mt-1"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M5.293 7.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 10.586l3.293-3.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414l-4 4a1 1 0 01-1.414 0l-4-4a1 1 0 010-1.414z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path></svg>
                </button>
                <div x-show="open" x-transition:enter="transition ease-out duration-100" x-transition:enter-start="transform opacity-0 scale-95" x-transition:enter-end="transform opacity-100 scale-100" x-transition:leave="transition ease-in duration-75" x-transition:leave-start="transform opacity-100 scale-100" x-transition:leave-end="transform opacity-0 scale-95" class="absolute right-0 w-full mt-2 origin-top-right rounded-md shadow-lg">
                        <div class="px-2 py-2 bg-white rounded-md shadow dark-mode:bg-gray-800">
                        <a class="block px-4 py-2 mt-2 text-sm font-semibold bg-transparent rounded-lg dark-mode:bg-transparent dark-mode:hover:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:text-white dark-mode:hover:text-white dark-mode:text-gray-200 md:mt-0 hover:text-gray-900 focus:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-200 focus:bg-gray-200 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" href="#">{{ __('Clients') }}</a>
                        <a class="block px-4 py-2 mt-2 text-sm font-semibold bg-transparent rounded-lg dark-mode:bg-transparent dark-mode:hover:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:text-white dark-mode:hover:text-white dark-mode:text-gray-200 md:mt-0 hover:text-gray-900 focus:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-200 focus:bg-gray-200 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" href="#">{{ __('Profesionals') }}</a>
                        <a class="block px-4 py-2 mt-2 text-sm font-semibold bg-transparent rounded-lg dark-mode:bg-transparent dark-mode:hover:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:text-white dark-mode:hover:text-white dark-mode:text-gray-200 md:mt-0 hover:text-gray-900 focus:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-200 focus:bg-gray-200 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" href="#">{{ __('System users') }}</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="absolute bottom-0 my-8">
                <a class="block px-4 py-2 mt-2 text-xl font-medium text-gray-900 bg-transparent rounded-lg hover:text-gray-900 focus:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-200 focus:bg-gray-200 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" href="{{ route('logout') }}" onclick="event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();"><i class='font-medium mr-5 text-xl bx bx-exit text-green-600'></i>{{ __('Log out') }}</a>
                <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" class="d-none">
                @csrf
                </form>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>   
</div>
```

[this is how it looks when I add the fixed class, when I remove looks normal sidebar on the left calendar on the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8JWL.jpg)

I don't know what is wrong

Answer (score 38):

**A simple Tailwind layout to create a sticky sidebar and scrollable content next to it.**

```
<div class="flex">
    <aside class="h-screen sticky top-0">
        // Fixed Sidebar
    </aside>

    <main>
        // Content
    </main>
</div>
```

Comment: Source: https://gist.github.com/BjornDCode/5cb836a6b23638d6d02f5cb6ed59a04a

Answer (score 10):

Santiago, checkout [flex layout working example](https://play.tailwindcss.com/uOnWQzR9tl) where you don't need to use static or fixed rather a calculated flex layouts works just fine.

```
<main class="flex flex-col h-screen">
  <div class="flex flex-1 overflow-hidden">
    <div class="flex bg-gray-100 w-32 p-4">Sidebar</div>
    <div class="flex flex-1 flex-col">
      <div class="flex bg-gray-300 h-16 p-4">Header</div>
      <div class="flex flex-1 bg-blue-300 overflow-y-auto paragraph px-4">
        Creative Writing Generating random paragraphs can be an excellent way for writers to get their creative flow going at the beginning of the day. The writer has no idea what topic the random paragraph will be about when it appears. This forces the writer to use creativity to complete one of three common writing challenges. The writer can use the paragraph as the first one of a short story and build upon it. A second option is to use the random paragraph somewhere in a short story they create. The third option is to have the random paragraph be the ending paragraph in a short story. No matter which of these challenges is undertaken, the writer is forced to use creativity to incorporate the paragraph into their writing. Tackle Writers' Block A random paragraph can also be an excellent way for a writer to tackle writers' block. Writing block can often happen due to being stuck with a current project that the writer is trying to complete. By inserting a completely random paragraph from which to begin, it can take down some of the issues that may have been causing the writers' block in the first place. Beginning Writing Routine Another productive way to use this tool to begin a daily writing routine. One way is to generate a random paragraph with the intention to try to rewrite it while still keeping the original meaning. The purpose here is to just get the writing started so that when the writer goes onto their day's writing projects, words are already flowing from their fingers. Writing Challenge Another writing challenge can be to take the individual sentences in the random paragraph and incorporate a single sentence from that into a new paragraph to create a short story. Unlike the random sentence generator, the sentences from the random paragraph will have some connection to one another so it will be a bit different. You also won't know exactly how many sentences will appear in the random paragraph. Creative Writing Generating random paragraphs can be an excellent way for writers to get their creative flow going at the beginning of the day. The writer has no idea what topic the random paragraph will be about when it appears. This forces the writer to use creativity to complete one of three common writing challenges. The writer can use the paragraph as the first one of a short story and build upon it. A second option is to use the random paragraph somewhere in a short story they create. The third option is to have the random paragraph be the ending paragraph in a short story. No matter which of these challenges is undertaken, the writer is forced to use creativity to incorporate the paragraph into their writing. Tackle Writers' Block A random paragraph can also be an excellent way for a writer to tackle writers' block. Writing block can often happen due to being stuck with a current project that the writer is trying to complete. By inserting a completely random paragraph from which to begin, it can take down some of the issues that may have been causing the writers' block in the first place. Beginning Writing Routine Another productive way to use this tool to begin a daily writing routine. One way is to generate a random paragraph with the intention to try to rewrite it while still keeping the original meaning. The purpose here is to just get the writing started so that when the writer goes onto their day's writing projects, words are already flowing from their fingers. Writing Challenge Another writing challenge can be to take the individual sentences in the random paragraph and incorporate a single sentence from that into a new paragraph to create a short story. Unlike the random sentence generator, the sentences from the random paragraph will have some connection to one another so it will be a bit different. You also won't know exactly how many sentences will appear in the random paragraph. Creative Writing Generating random paragraphs can be an excellent way for writers to get their creative flow going at the beginning of the day. The writer has no idea what topic the random paragraph will be about when it appears. This forces the writer to use creativity to complete one of three common writing challenges. The writer can use the paragraph as the first one of a short story and build upon it. A second option is to use the random paragraph somewhere in a short story they create. The third option is to have the random paragraph be the ending paragraph in a short story. No matter which of these challenges is undertaken, the writer is forced to use creativity to incorporate the paragraph into their writing. Tackle Writers' Block A random paragraph can also be an excellent way for a writer to tackle writers' block. Writing block can often happen due to being stuck with a current project that the writer is trying to complete. By inserting a completely random paragraph from which to begin, it can take down some of the issues that may have been causing the writers' block in the first place. Beginning Writing Routine Another productive way to use this tool to begin a daily writing routine. One way is to generate a random paragraph with the intention to try to rewrite it while still keeping the original meaning. The purpose here is to just get the writing started so that when the writer goes onto their day's writing projects, words are already flowing from their fingers. Writing Challenge Another writing challenge can be to take the individual sentences in the random paragraph and incorporate a single sentence from that into a new paragraph to create a short story. Unlike the random sentence generator, the sentences from the random paragraph will have some connection to one another so it will be a bit different. You also won't know exactly how many sentences will appear in the random paragraph.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex">Footer</div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

As the Code below You Can grid page to some columns and set height equal to screen height  then set overflow-y-scroll to your page's main section. also you can set overflow-y-scroll to your sidebar as mine.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    @vite('resources/css/app.css')

</head>
<body class="flex justify-center items-center grid grid-cols-4">
    <div class="bg-[#eaeaea]  h-screen overflow-y-scroll">

    </div>
    <div class="col-span-3 h-screen overflow-y-scroll">

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**